# How to add mod_proxy_wstunnel to Apache2 2.2 on Raspberry Pi (Backport mod_proxy_wstunnel)

Tags: apache, websocket, raspberry-pi, mod-proxy, apache2-module

Raspberry Pi is still on Apache 2.2 (2.2.22-13+deb7u4 right now).
To use Apache as Proxy for Websockets ("ProxyPass") Apache Module mod_proxy_wstunnel is required.

Apache Module mod_proxy_wstunnel is available in httpd 2.4.5 and later.

How can I add mod_proxy_wstunnel to Apache2 2.2 on Raspberry Pi (Backport mod_proxy_wstunnel)?

Answer (score 8):

Download Apache Source, add patch from Vitkin, compile Apache and add module mod_proxy_wstunnel.so to Apache Modules

Details about the patch: https://gist.github.com/vitkin/6661683

Detailed steps:

```
# Check apache version (should be 2.2.22 as of writing, if not adjust the next step)
dpkg -s apache2

# Checkout apache source
svn checkout http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/tags/2.2.22/ httpd-2.2.22

# Get patch and apply it
wget https://gist.github.com/vitkin/6661683/raw/873dd8b4de4ad1ff69757ffe48fc574374aedc57/apache-2.2-wstunnel.patch
cd httpd-2.2.22
patch -p1 -i ../apache-2.2-wstunnel.patch

# Build Apache 
svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr/branches/1.4.x srclib/apr
svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr-util/branches/1.3.x srclib/apr-util
./buildconf # EDIT: Some commenters noted that buildconf should be run before the configure
./configure --enable-proxy=shared --enable-proxy_wstunnel=shared
make

# Copy the module to apache installation
sudo cp modules/proxy/.libs/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so /usr/lib/apache2/modules

# Create module load file
cd /etc/apache2/mods-available
sudo echo "LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so" > proxy_wstunnel.load

# Create symbolic link to load the module
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
sudo ln -s ../mods-available/proxy_wstunnel.load proxy_wstunnel.load

# Add ProxyPass to Site config
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available

# e.g. modify default site config with "sudo nano default"
# and add the following line inside the VirtualHost element:
# "ProxyPass /websockets/mywebsocket ws://mywebsocketserver.com/websockets/mywebsocket"

# Restart Apache
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: When I tried this, I got the following after "sudo service apache2 restart":
    apache2: Syntax error on line 253 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mod_proxy_wstunnel.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so: undefined symbol: ap_proxy_canonenc – and so action 'configtest' failed. Any ideas?

Comment: The solution was that you have to copy not just mod_proxy_wstunnel but mod_proxy as well, as seen here: https://www.amoss.me.uk/2013/06/apache-2-2-websocket-proxying-ubuntu-mod_proxy_wstunnel/

Comment: In my raspbian apache is version 2.4.10, but the mod_proxy_wstunnel is still not available. according to the apache documentation it should be there. Any idea why?

Comment: Typo in echo command: output redirect should be to filename 'proxy_wstunnel.load' not 'mod_proxy_wstunnel.load'

Comment: @alexmogavero have you tried `a2enmod proxy_wstunnel.load`?

Answer (score 4):

I followed these steps for CentOS 2.2, assuming for Raspberry Pi it should be on similiar lines. I have invested lot of time figuring this out and there is very little documentation available for this. Let me know if this helps, else I can help you troubleshooting the problem. Also hope this helps to future readers.

To compile `mod_proxy_tunnel.so`,

1. `yum install httpd-devel`
2. Download the `mod_proxy_tunnel.c` and compile it using `apxs -i -a -c mod_proxy_tunnel.c`

Then load the above compiled module in `/etc/httpd/modules`:

1. Copy the `mod_proxy_wstunnel.so` in `/etc/httpd/modules` (Compiled from above)
2. In order to load the module while the server starts, use `LoadModule` directive in the httpd conf file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

   Add the following line with all other LoadModule line

   ```
   LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
   ```
3. To restart apache use `service httpd restart`
4. To check the loaded modules in apache after restarting use `httpd -M`
5. After the module is installed, add these two lines in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

   ```
   ProxyPass /websockets/mywebsocket ws://mywebsocketserver.com//websockets/mywebsocket retry=4
   ProxyPassReverse /websockets/mywebsocket ws://mywebsocketserver.com//websockets/mywebsocket retry=4
   ```

Note : Make sure the above lines are added before the default case of `/`. Also restart apache just to be safe.

Answer (score 3):

I needed this for my installation of the [Traccar site](http://www.traccar.org). I did an apt-update /apt-upgrade. I executed **dpkg -s apache2** which showed I was running **Version: 2.2.22-13+deb7u7**. I started following the instructions in [LearningAboutTech's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31255503/1763157).
In the time passed, some of the process changed:

1. I started with **apt-get install apache2-threaded-dev**
2. I then sought out mod_proxy_wstunnel.c, I used the version [here](https://gist.github.com/bodgit/80a2fb09170596589a03), and fetched it with wget
3. I then used the command **apxs2 -i -a -c mod_proxy_wstunnel.c**
4. After checking the configuration files, I saw that the module was
   already loaded in the **mods-enabled** folder.
5. I had already added the ProxyPass and ProxyReverse in the site configuration files. So, the next thing was to **service apache2 restart** and test.

Testing the site, it performed as expected, I did see warnings in the error
file:

> [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /api/socket. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.

At some point, I will look into this further - it may be related to what I have just done or some other configuration in my setup - but I'm happy my site is working as expected!